# Visual Studio 2013 no longer debugs MSTests

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, mstest

I have a bunch of MSTests that can no longer be step into or debugged.  I have breakpoints set but for some reason, Visual Studio ignores them while executing the tests.

I have cleaned the project and rebuilt, deleted the test results folder found under the solution root and also restarted Visual Studio all to no avail.  Only  thing I have not done yet is restart my machine.

Anyone know what the problem could be here?

Comment: Tests sometimes don't work if you switch architecture. Could that be your case?

Comment: @Alegnem, all projects in the solution have platform as Any CPU.  Interesting enough some tests in the same test class can be debugged.